# Typescrip Mapping One Object to Another

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having difficulty in mapping one object to another object in Type script especially when objects contain different types and properties

```
interface PassengerV1 {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    address: Address;
    temp1:strng;
    temp2:string;
    phoneNumbers: PhoneNumber[]; 
}

interface PassengerV2 {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  address: Address;
}

interface ObjectA{
  lossCause: string;
  lossDate: string;
  vehicleInformation: {
    vehicle: [
      {
        passengerInformation: {
        passenger: PassengerV1[];};
      }
    ];
  };
}

interface ObjectB{
  lCause: string;
  lDate: string;
  vehicleInfo: {
    vehicle: [
       {
         passengerInformation: {
         passenger: PassengerV2[];
       };
    ];
  };
}

const requestData: ObjectB= {
   lCause: ObjectA.lossCause,
   lDate: ObjectA.lossDate,
   vehicleInformation: vehicleInfo??
}
```

Above is the ObjectB, iam building from Object A but got stuck with vehicle information. Researched map, objectfromentries but not clear how can be applied with child types differ in properties?

Comment: Why your `vehicle` is an array of exactly one element? Or is it an array of multiple elements but typed incorrectly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm afraid I don't understand what your problem is.  What specifically is your question?  Please review the guidelines for [ask] as well as what makes a [mre].  Currently your code doesn't clearly point to a problem except for what looks like unrelated issues (typos, undefined types, undefined values).